# WP7 - Different data Binding according to query string

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a panorama page with a list of some items. When the user clicks each one of them it goes to a page that has some more info( image, textblock, etc). The page format is the same for any item you click on the panorama but with different information.

What is the best way to do this? I'm thinking of having one page and depending what item the user clicked on the panorama it loads the same page but with different ItemViewModel Binding.

Is that possible? Or do I have to create separate pages for every item of the panorama page?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I found the solution on another page. Here it is in case someone else searches the same thing

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-MVVM-Master---Details-Navigation-in-5-minutes